# Bitbucket 'Downloads' section storage limit

Tags: git, bitbucket, storage, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm considering storing binaries of my repos in their 'Downloads' section within Bitbuckte. Does anyone know if there is a limit to how big a file can be and how much we can store in the 'Downloads' section? I've searched and can't find anything that indicates a limit - I just want to be sure before I start packing things into the 'Downloads' section.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/what-kind-of-limits-do-you-have-on-repository-file-upload-size-273877699.html) it seems that there is no explicit limit to this size (other than 2GB per file), which is confusing. I've played around recently trying to find this out.

Uploading a file to the "Downloads" section of a repo does not increase the `Git Large File Storage` usage or increase the `Size` usage according to the repo settings page.

I can only assume that it gets lumped into the overall cloud storage size, but isn't shown to the user anywhere.